# How do I make custom query with WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to make a query in a WordPress plugin but I couldn't find a WordPress function and I'm not sure is right to use mysql_query

The functions I've found enable ordering and grouping but I need to use also join and in (list).

Is there a way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you'd want to use the `$wpdb` class (which has functions for directly accessing and manipulating the wordpress database).  It lets you do things like:

```
<?php $wpdb->query('select * from my_plugin_table where foo = "bar"'); ?>
```

[Documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class).

Comment: Note to anyone looking at this answer as it comes up on the first page of Google results, it will just return the number of rows affected for this and some other queries and in other cases it will return true. If you want to get data then use `$wpdb->get_results`

Answer (score 17):

To pull out rows maybe you'd use:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```